# Trello API: Programatically Adding Line Breaks to Card Descriptions

Tags: line-breaks, trello

When manually entering a Trello card's description, it's easy to introduce line breaks: just press ENTER. However, I need to introduce line breaks when setting a card's description **via the Trello API.** So far, \n and < br > don't get parsed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to find this and are looking to add a line break using the URL from the API, use `%0A`.

For example:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=(key)&token=(token)&name=(card name)&desc=Line 1 %0A Line 2 %0A Line 3&idList=<id>
```

Comment: Works very nice in PHP

Answer (score 4):

Struggled with this problem for ages. 
The php in WisdmLabs' answer works if it's passed as php to an element and then to js through getElementByID, but that's not possible if you need to set the variable clientside.

Finally found \x0A works in js.

Hope this saves someone from the hours of googling I endured!

Comment: Also works in R with `httr::POST` (yes, I connected RStudio Projects to Trello). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I got the solution to add Line break in trello card description, if you are using php. 
Try like this,

```
$card_desc =  $some_text . "\xA" . $some_more_text;
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I'm coming from .NET, so I used concatenation around **Environment.NewLine** calls to introduce new lines. Trello respected these as line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with whatever works best in your current language.

So far, known working line breaks are:

- PHP: PHP_EOL (= \n)
- .NET: Environment.NewLine
- JS: \x0A
- URl linebreak: %0A

Answer (score 0):

Here '\x0A' works in python very well.

So..

PHP: PHP_EOL (= \n)
.NET: Environment.NewLine
JS / PYTHON: \x0A
URl linebreak: %0A

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.